# Change Inner Select Value in Lambda Expression C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a query in Lambda expression. i want to encode a properties which in two step inner in query.
The sample code is

```
 public List<StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel> GetCreativeQuestionsByQuestionSetId(long studentId,
            long questionSetId)
        {
            var questionList =
                UnitOfWork.StudentExamRepository.GetCreativeQuestionsByQuestionSetId(studentId, questionSetId);

            List<StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel> encryptQuestionList = questionList.Select(q =>
            {
                q.Questions = q.Questions.Select(t =>
                {
                    t.TutorialList.Select(x =>
                    {
                        x.FileName = x.FileName.ToEncode();
                        return x;
                    });
                    return t;
                });
                return q;
            }).ToList();
            return encryptQuestionList.ToList();

        }
```

and GetCreativeQuestionsByQuestionSetId exist in another layer having code:

```
  public IEnumerable<StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel> GetCreativeQuestionsByQuestionSetId(long studentId, long questionSetId)
        {
            bool isPurchased = this.IsPurchased(studentId);
            var data = (from question in Context.Question
                join questionSetQuestion in Context.QuestionSetQuestion on question.Id equals questionSetQuestion
                    .QuestionId
                where questionSetQuestion.QuestionSetId == questionSetId && question.IsArchived == false
                select new StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel
                {
                    Id = question.Id,
                    Name = question.Name,
                    Mark = questionSetQuestion.Mark,
                    LastUpdateDate = question.LastUpdateDate,
                    ImageUrl = question.ImageUrl,
                    Questions = Context.CreativeQuestion.Where(qa => qa.QuestionId == question.Id).AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(cq => new CreativeQuestionViewModel
                        {
                            Id = cq.Id,
                            Name = cq.Name,
                            TutorialList = (from aSuggestion in Context.AnswerSuggestion
                                join t in Context.Tutorial on aSuggestion.TutorialId equals t.Id
                                where aSuggestion.CreativeQuestionId == cq.Id &&
                                      t.TutorialType >= TutorialType.Video &&
                                      t.TutorialType <= TutorialType.Link
                                group t by t.TutorialType into grp
                                select grp.OrderBy(g => g.TutorialType).FirstOrDefault() into tutorial
                                join st in Context.StudentTutorial.Where(s => s.StudentId == studentId) on tutorial.Id equals st.TutorialId into sTutorialTemp
                                from sTutorial in sTutorialTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join topic in Context.Topic on tutorial.TopicId equals topic.Id into topicGroup
                                from tp in topicGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join chapter in Context.Chapter on tutorial.ChapterId equals chapter.Id into chapterGrp
                                from c in chapterGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join bk in Context.Bookmark on tutorial.Id equals bk.TutorialId into tempBk
                                from bookmark in tempBk.Where(t => t.StudentId == studentId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new TutorialListViewModel
                                {
                                    Id = tutorial.Id,
                                    Body = tutorial.Body,
                                    Heading = tutorial.Heading,
                                    FileName = tutorial.FileName,
                                    ThumbUrl = tutorial.ThumbUrl,
                                    ChapterName = c.Name,
                                    TutorialType = tutorial.TutorialType,
                                    DurationInSecond = tutorial.DurationInSecond,
                                    TopicId = tutorial.TopicId,
                                    Sequence = tp != null ? tp.SequenceNumber:0,
                                    IsLocked = tutorial.IsLocked && !isPurchased,
                                    IsCompleted = sTutorial != null && sTutorial.IsCompleted,
                                    IsBookmark = bookmark != null
                                }).ToList()
                        }).ToList()
                }).AsEnumerable();

            return data;
        }
```

Here show the error to cast this query. the message shown:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel> encryptQuestionList = questionList.Select(q =>
            {
                q.Questions = q.Questions.Select(t =>
                {
                    t.TutorialList = t.TutorialList.Select(x =>
                    {
                        x.FileName = x.FileName.ToEncode();
                        return x;
                    }).ToList();
                    return t;
                }).ToList();
                return q;
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing with `q.Questions = q.Questions.Select(t =>...` while creating the `encryptedQuestionList` is causing the cast exception as the 'q.Questions' is of type 'List' and you are trying to assign an 'IEnumerable' to it within that query.

The `encryptedQuestionList` query can be written like this:

```
List<StudentCreativeQuestionListViewModel> encryptQuestionList = questionList.Select(q =>
            {
                q.Questions.Select(t =>
                {
                    t.TutorialList.Select(x =>
                    {
                        x.FileName = x.FileName.ToEncode();
                        return x;
                    });
                    return t;
                });
                return q;
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: this solution is fix the bug but do not fill the purpose. By the way, it solved. thanks for your contribution